# Asp.net - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

I am using the following to control user log in authentication. This redirects fine when the user is inactive or locked out, but when the user is deleted from the database, I get an error message...

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on this line...

```
If currentuser IsNot Nothing And currentuser.IsApproved = False Or currentuser.IsLockedOut = True Then
```

What could be causing this to happen?

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then

        Dim currentuser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()

        If currentuser IsNot Nothing And currentuser.IsApproved = False Or currentuser.IsLockedOut = True Then
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
        End If

        If currentuser IsNot Nothing Then
            Response.Redirect("~/media")
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `If` condition to:

```
If currentuser IsNot Nothing Then
  If currentuser.IsApproved = False Or currentuser.IsLockedOut = True Then
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
  End If

  Response.Redirect("~/media")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parathesize the second part and use `OrElse/AndAlso`, otherwise `currentuser IsNot Nothing`  will not be applied to all parts of your `if`

So this will fix it:

```
If currentuser IsNot Nothing AndAlso (Not currentuser.IsApproved OrElse currentuser.IsLockedOut) Then
```

Don't use `Or` (and `AND`) but `OrElse` (and `AndAlso`) which will short circuit. That means it will not evaluate the second part if the first part was already `true`. `Or` (and `And`) on the other side will evaluate both parts *always*.

Answer (score 1):

Since 'And' receives precedence over 'Or' the expression will
be evaluated as follows:

```
If
{ 
  currentuser IsNot Nothing And currentuser.IsApproved = False //condition 1
  Or 
  currentuser.IsLockedOut = True //condition 2
}
Then..
```

If current user is in fact nothing:
condition 1- will not fail, but condition 2 will throw
an exception since the code is trying to evaluate `(nothing).somthing.`

To fix the problem you'll have to add parentheses as shown:

```
If
  currentuser IsNot Nothing //condition 1
  And 
  (currentuser.IsApproved = False Or currentuser.IsLockedOut = True) //condition 2
Then..
```

Now, the 2nd condition will be evaluated only if the first condition is true.